# Keep somewhere additional data after backbone's collection fetched

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, fetch

I receive next data from server after get request:

```
{ data: { items: [...], itemsCount: Number } }
```

I'm saving items in backbone collection in next way:

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.data.items;
}
```

How do I keep somehow in collection or outer itemsCount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is straight forward. You're not limited to simply saving data in a collection or in the model.attributes hash.  Backbone objects are traditional javascript objects and you can create any custom property you'd like.

So, in your parse function, you could do...

```
parse: function (response) {
    this.itemsCount = response.itemsCount
    return response.data.items
}
```

Note that I am assuming that your parse function is scoped to the collection.  If it's not, then I need to see more code to demonstrate how to properly scope the function.